# Adjust height according to number of lines

Tags: ios, uilabel

I am trying to adjust height of my view according to how many lines inserted text will take. Then [title numberOfLines] always returns 0 instead of the new number of lines. Is there a way to get current number of lines?

```
UILabel *title = [[ UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 80, 320, 50)];
[title setNumberOfLines:0];
float height = 32 * [title numberOfLines];
[self setFrame:CGRectMake(0, yCoord, 320, height)];
```

Comment: Your code doesn't make sense (without further explanation). You are creating a label, but then you are not adding that label to the interface. Moreover, what you are adjusting the frame of is not the label, but `self`. Plus, the label has no text, so there's nothing to size to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up using

```
[title sizeToFit];
int numLines = (int)(title.frame.size.height/title.font.leading);
```

From another answer

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem come from the fact you did n't set any text and font to your UILabel.

What you could use is [[UIView sizeToFit]](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIView/sizeToFit)

Here is a short sample code:

```
    UILabel *title = [[ UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 80, 320, 50)];
    [title setText:@"An awesome title very long or something really important like a Lorem Ipsum"]; // a text to base the needed numbers of line on
    [title setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:18]]; // don't forget the font
    [title setNumberOfLines:0];
    [title sizeToFit]; // now the label will be resize to display all lines
    [title setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 80, 320, title.frame.size.height)]; // reset the width in case the sizeToFit method resized it wrong.
```

Comment: I forgot to put it in the code snippet. I actually have text assigned to UILabel, the number if lines stays the same

Comment: is the resizing working with the sizeToFit method? do your text is long enough ? 
The method `numberOfLines` [link](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UILabel_Class/Reference/UILabel.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UILabel/numberOfLines) will always return 0 because it's the value to avoid any size limitation.
It always returns what you set before, in this case `[title setNumberOfLines:0];`